# Why does Spring instantiates my prototype before it is called?

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have the need to set a sessionFactory as a prototype, so I can create it from the code.

```
<bean id="sessionFactoryResult"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" scope="prototype">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSourceResult" />
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties" ref="hibernatePropertiesResult" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="package.entity"/>
</bean>
```

Later in my code I have:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = (SessionFactory) ctx.getBean("sessionFactoryResult");
```

However for some reasons, Spring instantiates this sessionFactory (and creates the database) at the start of the application... 
And as a side note: when I finally call it from the code, hibernate does not recreate the database (I need to programmatically modify the datasource before any sessionFactory instantiation)

Comment: Any chance you could spellcheck your question before posting?

Comment: Try adding `lazy-init="true"` to bean definition.

Comment: Sorry I'm not an english native speaker.

I tried the lazy-init but the problem remains.
    <bean id="sessionFactoryResult"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" scope="prototype" lazy-init="true">

Comment: Actually Lazy worked!
I just had to also put it on prototypes  that were calling the sessionFactory

Answer (score 0):

Answer given by Predrag Maric, lazy-init="true" on spring beans, or @Lazy

Answer (score 0):

As alternative, if you want get more control in your instantiation chain of beans, you can determine the instantiation order implementing the Phased interface in them.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/Phased.html

Excample.

```
@Service
public class FooSessionFactory implements Phased{

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public int getPhase() {

        return -1;
    }    
}
```